# Relationship with a table without unique/primary key

Tags: primary-key, unique-constraint

I have a database with 3 tables.

Table `Work`, with a field named `workName`.

Table `SubWorks`, which have a field `subWorkName` and `work` with a relationship with `Work.workName`.

And table `Activity` with field `superworkname` which should have a relationship with `SubWorks.subWorkName`.

I can't create this relationship because `SubWorks.subWorkName` is not an unique key (or primary key, it just don't appear in phpMyAdmin) and it can't be because it's allowed to have multiple `SubWorks` with the same name until `Work.workName` is different between them.

How can i resolve this situation? I'm thinking about using a primary key int, but what if one day i go in overflow? Suppose i got so much works to store that i go out the limit?

---

I added an `ID` column to `Activity` so i can differentiate them

That's what i want to do with relationships:

I have a `Work` named `R1`.

3 SubWorks, named: `R1-1`, `R1-2`, `R1-3` with a relationship to R1.

And 2 Activity (ID: 1, 2), with refer with subWorkName to `R1-1`.
And another activity with ID 3, which refer with subWorkName to `R1-2`

I want, if i delete R1: `R1-1`, `R1-2`, `R1-3` will be deleted too and with them all their activity, so activity 1 and 2 will be deleted to.

Now, suppose i delete `R1-1`, activity ID 1 and 2 should be deleted too.

If i delete `R1-2` activity ID 3 should be deleted.

I already did the first part (if i delete a Work, SubWork will gone with it) but i had problem with the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using surrogate IDs is one way but you don't really have to. If you want to keep your current design - which I suppose has `Work (workName)` as primary key and `SubWork (workName, subWorkName)` as a potential primary or unique key, you can define the `Activity` table like this (I also changed slightly the column names):

```
Work
--------
workName      PK


SubWork
--------
workName      PK ,  FK -> Work (workName)
subWorkName   PK


Activity 
-------- 
activityID    PK       -- or what other column you have as primary key
workName        FK1
subWorkName     FK1  
  FK1 (workName, subWorkName) -> SubWork (workName, subWorkName)
```

As @raumkrieger points out, to define a foreign key constraint you have to reference a unique or primary key column (or columns.) Since if we assume correctly that `(workName, subWorkName)` unique identifies a row in the `SubWork` table, you can use this combination to be referenced by the foreign key.

---

Note: I do not suggest that using long varchar columns is always better than using narrow surrogate integer columns. Especially if the tables are big (or plan to be) and/or the varchar columns are very wide, this will not be the most efficient design in most DBMS. But for narrow varchar columns and/or smaller tables, the difference in performance will be negligible.

Comment: Making subWorkName of SubWork Primary Key then i would not be able to create a new SubWork with the same name but different workName. Right?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno No, my suggestion is to make the combination `(workName, subWorkName)` the primary key of `SubWork`. So, you could have 2 subworks with same name and different workname. Or with same workname and different name. But not 2 rows with same workname and same name.

Comment: What is activityColumn?

Comment: I edited my answer with what i want to do.

Comment: I should have named that `ActivityID` or something similar. You had not mentioned that table's primary key.

Answer (score 2):

Primary keys (and foreign keys) should be unique, otherwise how does the database know which row the foreign key relationship is pointing to?

> I'm thinking about using a primary key int, but what if one day i go in overflow? Suppose i got so much works to store that i go out the limit?

I wouldn't worry about hitting the limit for ints. [The mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html) lists the limits of various int types. If you're concerned about having more than 2 billion rows anytime soon, you can always use `bigint` and have over 9 quintillion rows before overflowing. 18 quintillion if you used unsigned.